# References on how to calculate quantile of a population from a small sample

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, estimation, quantiles, small-sample

I'm a novice in statistics. I need to study a problem that basically consists in checking if the 5% quantile of a population (that can be assumed normally distributed) is above or below a given value from a very small sample (15 values). I don't know the mean nor the standard deviation of the population, so both will have to be estimated from the sample. Presumibly I will need to define a confidence interval for that testing.

I need help on how to solve such a problem and references on the background theory I need to study to approach such a problem. Please be specific if you can.

Thank you for any help you could provide me.

Comment: This problem calls for a *tolerance limit* (a phrase you could search on).

Comment: @whuber Yeah, tolerance limits are what I was looking for. Thank you, you saved me from digging into thousands of pages of statistics. For future readers of this post, I read the introductory part of this book "Statistical tolerance regions, Theory, Applications, and Computation" and it was very helpful. Hope this can help someone else in future.

Comment: @xanz if you found answer to your question you can always post it as an answer to your question -- it'd be nice, since it'd let others learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent Excel file has been compiled to allow for the use of calculating [Hazen Percentiles](http://cws.msu.edu/water_info/documents/hazen-percentile-calculator_updated.xls).  The file not only contains information regarding this particular method (which is useful for percentile with small sample sizes), but it also includes several other percentile calculations.

---

From the file:

> Calculation procedure
>     Say you have n data, Xi, such that i = 1, 2, … , n. The Hazen procedure used is:
>
> 1 Rank the n data from lowest to highest; call these ranked data Yi: i = 1, 2, …, n.
>
> 2 Compute the percentile fraction (i.e., proportion) as p = P/100
>
> 3 Check if there are enough data to make the calculation, i.e., if
>           n >= 1/[2(1-p)] and n >= 1/(2p)
>           [the first limit applies for an upper percentile (p > 1/2), and vice versa]
>
> 4 If there are enough data then calculate the Hazen rank (usually non-integer)
>           rHazen = 1/2 + pn
>
> 5 Interpolate between integer ranks (i.e., ranked data) adjacent to the Hazen rank using
>           Hazen Pth percentile = (1-rf)Yri + rfYri+1
>           where ri = the integer part of rHazen and rf = fractional part of rHazen
>           [note that the formula still works if there is just enough data, i.e., for
>           equalities, instead of inequalities, in the equations in item 3 above]
>
> Note that there is no one correct way to calculate percentiles. The Hazen method is a
>       "middle-of-the-road" option. Other estimators use the same procedure but with a
>       different minimum number of data and a different r formula (in Steps 3 & 4), as follows:
>
> rBlom =     3/8 + p(n+1/4), requiring           n >= (3+2p)/[8(1-p)] and n >= (5-2p)/(8p)
>       rTukey =    1/3 + p(n+1/3), requiring           n >= (1+p)/[3(1-p)] and n >= (2-p)/(3p)
>       rWeibull =  p(n+1), requiring           n >= p/(1-p) and n >= (1-p)/p
>       rExcel =    1 + p(n-1), requiring           n >= 1 (which is dashed odd!)
>       (The Excel option always give the lowest percentile; Weibull always gives the highest.)
>
> For more details see chapter 8 of McBride, G.B. (2005). Ysing Statistical Methods for
>       Water Quality Management: Issues, Problemns and Solutions,Wiley, New York.